# C# alert message if gridview specific column value is below zero while clicking button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bring alert message while clicking button and criteria is Gridview specific column value is below zero.

Existing code is:

```c#
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            var countForZero = from GridViewRow gr in gvEmployeeDetails.Rows
                               where (gr.FindControl("Literal4") as Label).Text.Equals("0")
                               select gr.ToList();

            if (countForZero > 0)
            {
                Messagebox("Messagebox Pop up Alert!!!");
            }

            BindGrid();
        }
    }
        private void Messagebox(string Message)
    {
        Label lblMessageBox = new Label();
        lblMessageBox.Text =
            "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "window.alert('" + Message + "')</script>";
        Page.Controls.Add(lblMessageBox);
    }
```

```aspx
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AGREEDVSISSUED" >
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:label 
       ID="Literal4" 
       runat="server" 
       Text='<%# ok(Eval("agreed").ToString(), Eval("total_issued").ToString() )%>'>
    </asp:label>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind javascript click event to the button. You can use `Button1.Attributes.Add` in Page load for instance, see this How to: [Set HTML Attributes for Controls in ASP.NET Web Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx)

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick",  "window.alert('" + Message + "')";
```

If button is in the GridView then you would have to bind click event to button in each Row, you can do that in [RowDataBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {    
        Button Button1 = (Button)e.Row.FindControls("Button1");
        //Similarly get the elements from GridView as I go button and see if criteria need alert on button and bind event.
       if(conditionBasedOnOtherColumnValues)
            Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick",  "window.alert('" + Message + "')"; 
    } 
}
```

**Edit** based on edit in OP, instead of adding script tag in label text use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx) that will be executed on Page load after button click if you register it.

```
private void Messagebox(string Message)
{
    String csname1 = "GridButtonScript";        
    Type cstype = this.GetType();    
    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    //if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1)) //You may or may not need this condition.
    {
      String cstext1 = "alert('" + Message + "');";
      cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, true);
    }    
}
```

Comment: hi button is not in the gridview. tried following but getting error ,

Comment: What error you get, I updated my answer based on change in your questions.

Comment: hi this is my current code . should i keep the same and add yours or ?

Comment: Replace your Messagebox function with mine and if you do not get the expected result then debug and let me know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

yes.Its working with updated one. I am able to see my result.